# 平方数の判定を、sympyの素因数分解factorintでできますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム, sympy

目的は、平方数の判定を一行でできますか?よろしくお願いします。

print(factorint(9))
{3: 2}
print(factorint(81))
{3: 4}

参考nが平方数かどうか調べる時
https://teratail.com/questions/200122

参考:Wolfram|Alpha
81は平方数ですか
https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=81%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

80は平方数ですか
https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=80%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Comment: 参考: [sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正の数 n に対して、n を素因数分解した結果すべての素因数の指数が偶数であることが n が平方数であることの必要十分条件ですから、素因数分解できているのであれば指数がすべて偶数であるかどうかをチェックすれば良いです。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73657/sympyに-平方数判定-is-square-がありますが-factorintで一行でできますか