# sympy に平方数を判定する is_square がありますが、factorint で一行でできますか？

Tags: sympy

短くなりますか？　よろしくお願いします。

```
def My_is_square(x):
    myDic=factorint(x)
    i=0
    for k, v in myDic.items():
        if v % 2 == 0:
           i=i+1
    if i == len(myDic):
       return True
    else:
      return False

from sympy import *
print("  9",My_is_square(  9))
print(" 80",My_is_square( 80))
print(" 81",My_is_square( 81))
print("400",My_is_square(400))
#   9 True
#  80 False
#  81 True
# 400 True
```

(2021-01-30) 追加

```
print("  1",My_is_square(  1))
print("  0",My_is_square(  0))
print(" -3",My_is_square( -3))
print(" -4",My_is_square( -4))
#  1 True
#  0 True
# -3 False
# -4 False
```

(参考)Wolfram|Alpha
1は平方数ですか
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B&lang=ja
1は完全平方数です

0は平方数ですか
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B&lang=ja
0は完全平方数です

-3は平方数ですか
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B&lang=ja
-3は完全平方数ではありません

-4は平方数ですか
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%E3%81%AF%E5%B9%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B&lang=ja
-4は完全平方数ではありません

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73537/平方数の判定を-sympyの素因数分解factorintでできますか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一応、題目が「is_square がありますが、factorintで一行でできますか？」なので、返却値を [sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.is_square)([source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/9e8f62e059d83178c1d8a1e19acac5473bdbf1c1/sympy/ntheory/primetest.py#L59)) に合わせてみます。

```py
def My_is_square(x):
  return True if x in (0, 1) else all(y%2==0 for y in factorint(x).values())
```

以下、[sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint) からの抜粋です。

> For input less than 2, factorint behaves as follows:
>
> - factorint(1) returns the empty factorization, {}
> - factorint(0) returns {0:1}
> - factorint(-n) adds -1:1 to the factors and then factors n

Answer (score 1):

すべて(の値)が偶数か を調べるといいので, 次のようにできます

```py
for n in (9,80,81,400):
  issqr = all(v %2 == 0 for v in factorint(n).values())
  print(f'{n:3}, {My_is_square(n)}, {issqr}')
```

---

わかりにくいようなので, 抜粋します

```py
issqr = all(v %2 == 0 for v in factorint(n).values())
```

これを関数にしたければ

```py
def issqr(n):
  return all(v %2 == 0 for v in factorint(n).values())
```

(コメントにあるような '0' or '1' の処理は省いています)

Comment: 申し訳ありません。説明不足でした。My_is_squareの関数部分のつもりでした。

Comment: 関数で行う処理を 1行にしているわけですが？